# rails 4.2.1 server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

Hi I am new to rails and every time I try to view the server i get this

```
testapp$ rails s
/home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:48:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /home/sky/testapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sky/testapp/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /home/sky/testapp/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/sky/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/sky/testapp/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

what do?

Comment: Looks like you need to install a javascript runtime, just like the error suggests. Visit https://github.com/rails/execjs to find one that you like, install it, and give it a go.

Comment: please post your gem file

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that you have a JS runtime declared in your Gemfile.

Try adding:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

or

```
gem 'execjs'
```

to your Gemfile and run:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you need a JavaScript runtime. If you are unsure of which to choose, I've always been told to use [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/)